# Upload historic dsym files to firebase crash reporting

Tags: xamarin, firebase-crash-reporting, dsym, bitrise

We have a Xamarin forms app that is currently in production. We have Firebase crash reporting setup and we are receiving crash reports. We are using Bitrise.io as our build system and can get the .dsym files that we need. We are also a windows shop, so we have zero experience with xcode, cocopods, etc.

So the two questions that I have is:

1. How do we upload the current .dsym files we have to firebase crash reporting? (All the information I have found so far involves cocopods and a local build)
2. How do we configure the Xamarin project / Bitrise.io to automatically upload the dsym files in the future.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.